# Error MSG 213 Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Hi I'm trying to append the result of my query to another table, but i get the an error,  here is my code for the project

```
--create new table
create table tempweblogs
(
  date1 datetime
  users nvarchar(50)
  utotal int
  date2 datetime
  hostname nvarchar(50)
  htotal int
  date3 datetime
  srcip nvarchar(50)
  stotal int
)
--insert query result to tempweblogs table

insert into tempweblogs 
SELECT distinct top 10 
       Xdate as date1, Xuser as users, count (Xuser) as utotal 
from   weblogs 
where Xdate='2/16/2016'  and Xuser is not null 
group by Xuser, Xdate order by utotal  DESC    

SELECT distinct top 10 
       Xdate as date2, Xhostname as hostname, count(Xhostname) as htotal
from weblogs    
where Xdate='2/16/2016'  and xhostname is not null 
group by Xhostname, Xdate order by htotal DESC

SELECT distinct top 10 
       Xdate as date3, Xsrcip as srcip, count (Xsrcip) as stotal 
from weblogs 
where Xdate='2/16/2016'  and Xuser is not null 
group by Xsrcip, Xdate order by stotal  DESC
```

Comment: When using this kind of syntax, it must be expected that the number of values specified must match with the number of columns in the table. To make it work, explicitly declare the column names on where the values should be put in, eg. `INSERT INTO tempweblogs (date1, users, utotal) SELECT distinct top 10 
       Xdate as date1, Xuser as users, count (Xuser) as utotal ......`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should need to specify the column list in the INSERT statement

```
insert into tempweblogs ( date1 , users , utotal )
select ....
```

also you need the INSERT clause for all 3 query